# PHP - Caching a MySQL query and renew it periodically

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching

In my welcome page, I would like to show the total number of users registered with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS
```

Is this a bad idea to make a COUNT(*) query each time a user asks for the welcome page?

Would it be better to cache the result of this query, and then take this cached value to show on the welcome page and renew the value each 10 minutes for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a good idea is also to store the number of the registered user to your site (or the number of forum posts, blog entries, whatever number you need a `count(*)` to retrieve) as a counter in a separate table and increment - decrement the counter whenever a user resgister himself / cancel himself from the website (using triggers for example).

`COUNT (*)` queries can be quite heavy and in this way instead of a `count(*)` you could do `select counter from counter_table` which is pretty immidiate

> EDIT - Some info about COUNT() queries
>   taken from High performance mysql 2nd
>   edition
>
> Optimizing COUNT( ) Queries
>
> The COUNT( ) aggregate function and
>   how to optimize queries that use it is
>   probably one of the top 10 most
>   misunderstood topics in MySQL. You can
>   do a web search and find more
>   misinformation on this topic than we
>   care to think about. Before we get
>   into optimization, it’s important that
>   you understand what COUNT( ) really
>   does.
>
> What COUNT( ) does
>
> COUNT( ) is a special function that
>   works in two very different ways: it
>   counts values and rows. A value is a
>   non-NULL expression (NULL is the
>   absence of a value). If you specify a
>   column name or other expression inside
>   the parentheses, COUNT( ) counts how
>   many times that expression has a
>   value. This is confusing for many
>   people, in part because values and
>   NULL are confusing. If you need to
>   learn how this works in SQL, we
>   suggest a good book on SQL
>   fundamentals. (The Internet is not
>   necessarily a good source of accurate
>   information on this topic, either.)
>   The other form of COUNT( ) simply
>   counts the number of rows in the
>   result. This is what MySQL does when
>   it knows the expression inside the
>   parentheses can never be NULL. The
>   most obvious example is COUNT(*),
>   which is a special form of COUNT( )
>   that does not expand the * wildcard
>   into the full list of columns in the
>   table, as you might expect; instead,
>   it ignores columns altogether and
>   counts rows. One of the most common
>   mistakes we see is specifying column
>   names inside the parentheses when you
>   want to count rows. When you want to
>   know the number of rows in the result,
>   you should always use COUNT(*). This
>   communicates your intention clearly
>   and avoids poor performance.
>
> Myths about MyISAM
>
> A common misconception is that MyISAM
>   is extremely fast for COUNT( )
>   queries. It is fast, but only for a
>   very special case: COUNT(*) without a
>   WHERE clause, which merely counts the
>   number of rows in the entire table.
>   MySQL can optimize this away because
>   the storage engine always knows how
>   many rows are in the table. If MySQL
>   knows col can never be NULL, it can
>   also optimize a COUNT(col) expression
>   by converting it to COUNT(*)
>   internally. MyISAM does not have any
>   magical speed optimizations for
>   counting rows when the query has a
>   WHERE clause, or for the more general
>   case of counting values instead of
>   rows. It may be faster than other
>   storage engines for a given query, or
>   it may not be. That depends on a lot
>   of factors.
>
> Simple optimizations
>
> You can sometimes use MyISAM’s
>   COUNT(*) optimization to your
>   advantage when you want to count all
>   but a very small number of rows that
>   are well indexed. The following
>   example uses the standard World
>   database to show how you can
>   efficiently find the number of cities
>   whose ID is greater than 5. You might
>   write this query as follows: mysql>
>   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM world.City WHERE
>   ID > 5; If you profile this query with
>   SHOW STATUS, you’ll see that it scans
>   4,079 rows. If you negate the
>   conditions and subtract the number of
>   cities whose IDs are less than or
>   equal to 5 from the total number of
>   cities, you can reduce that to five
>   rows: mysql> SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM world.City) - COUNT(*)
>   -> FROM world.City WHERE ID <= 5; This version reads fewer rows because the
>   subquery is turned into a constant
>   during the query optimization phase,
>   as you can see with EXPLAIN:
>   ...+------+------------------------------+ | id | select_type | table |...| rows
>   | Extra |
>   ...+------+------------------------------+ | 1 | PRIMARY | City |...| 6 | Using
>   where; Using index | | 2 | SUBQUERY |
>   NULL |...| NULL | Select tables
>   optimized away |
>   ...+------+------------------------------+ A frequent question on mailing lists
>   and IRC channels is how to retrieve
>   counts for several different values in
>   the same column with just one query,
>   to reduce the number of queries
>   required. For example, say you want to
>   create a single query that counts how
>   many items have each of several
>   colors. You can’t use an OR (e.g.,
>   SELECT COUNT(color= 'blue' OR color=
>   'red') FROM items;), because that
>   won’t separate the different counts
>   for the different colors. And you
>   can’t put the colors in the WHERE
>   clause (e.g., SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   items WHERE color= 'blue' AND color=
>   'red';), because the colors are
>   mutually exclusive. Here is a query
>   that solves this problem: mysql>
>   SELECT SUM(IF(color = 'blue', 1, 0))
>   AS blue, SUM(IF(color = 'red', 1, 0))
>   -> AS red FROM items; And here is another that’s equivalent, but instead
>   of using SUM( ) uses COUNT( ) and
>   ensures that the expressions won’t
>   have values when the criteria are
>   false: mysql> SELECT COUNT(color =
>   'blue' OR NULL) AS blue, COUNT(color =
>   'red' OR NULL)
>   -> AS red FROM items;
>
> More complex optimizations
>
> In general, COUNT( ) queries are hard
>   to optimize because they usually need
>   to count a lot of rows (i.e., access a
>   lot of data). Your only other option
>   for optimizing within MySQL itself is
>   to use a covering index, which we
>   discussed in Chapter 3. If that
>   doesn’t help enough, you need to make
>   changes to your application
>   architecture. Consider summary tables
>   (also covered in Chapter 3), and
>   possibly an external caching system
>   such as memcached. You’ll probably
>   find yourself faced with the familiar
>   dilemma, “fast, accurate, and simple:
>   pick any two.”

Comment: Great tip Nicola. Also in the case of related tables (think about blog post table and post's comment table) using a column in the parent table (post) to store a counter of related items (comments) in child table can speed up queries. Also this can be modified by a trigger or in the add/remove child item code.

Comment: COUNT(*) on the entire table without condition are super faster. Also de-normalization isn't always a good option

Comment: @yes123 i've posted some info above about COUNT queries

Comment: guess I will remove that -1. Too much too read for me there lol

Comment: @yes123 what i posted doesn't mean that my proposed solution is perfect of course, it's just something i use (and of course i took from that book!)! :)

Answer (score 2):

On MyISAM that value is already cached.
So you don't need to cache it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect the count to change drastically, or in a way that really affects each user, you might experience a real savings by storing the `COUNT(*)` in `$_SESSION` for each user.  Then each only requests it once.  This is really a question of how important the timeliness of that data is to your users, and whether or not it is actually causing you a problem.

That said, if it is currently scaling the way you need it to, then it doesn't hurt to make the database call each time.  If you start having scalability issues, you can consider this as a possible action to take.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use cache engines like APC, xcache, or Memcache, then you don't need to cache that value.

The size of the entire table is a fast accessible thing.

Use xdebug to profile your application and find the **real** bottle-necks.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

A. Instead of `COUNT(*)`, do `COUNT(1)`. It's much faster.

B. Use caching like for example the Pear Cache module. The idea is to cache the number of users in a file in the filesystem.

**When to read from cache**: When reading the number of users on the welcome page, check if it already exists in the cache; if found read from there, else run the DB query.

**When to create the cache**: each time the count is retrieved from the database, the cache is created and count stored in it.

**When to invalidate cache**: whenever a user account is created or destroyed, the cache is invalidated (removed). Therefore, the next time when any user lands on the welcome page, the DB query will run and the cache will be regenerated. All future requests will then read from the Cache unless another user is created or destroyed.

I guess you might need some reading on Pear Cache but its easy and powerful.

Hope this helps.